# Getting unexpected newline error while doing awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am running the following script in linux command line:

```
ps -ef| grep "java -Droute=full" | awk 'NR!=1{print $2}' | while read output;
do
 pid=$(echo $output)
 kill $pid
done
```

I am getting the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: NR!=1{print
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I believe the quotes and spaces are consistent, but why am i still getting this error?

Output of `ps -ef | grep "java -Droute=full"`

```
root     24441     1  0 Apr22 ?        00:00:00 sudo nohup java -Droute=full -jar abc
root     24442 24441  7 Apr22 ?        06:41:10 java -Droute=full -jar abc
user  30804 30771  0 05:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java -Droute=full
```

Comment: can you show your output of `ps -ef| grep "java -Droute=full" `..?

Comment: @user3302647, Added in question itself.

Comment: @tanmay2507 why do you need `NR!=1`, are you using that to skip the header of `ps -ef`, if yes, you dont need that because `grep` already does that for you; just use `awk '{print $2}'` directly

Comment: I agree this should not produce that error, *assuming* your singlequotes are truly singlequotes (i.e. the key to the right of semicolon on US keyboard) and not some Unicode lookalike. However as a **workaround on most(?) Linux try `pkill -f`**.

Comment: Does this give you the same result? ps -ef | awk -F' ' '{ if ($0 ~ /java -Droute=full/) { print $2; kill $2 } }'

Comment: Another idea -> try to add a -Z to the grep command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem you're trying to solve is something like "How to kill the process whose command line contains `java -Droute=full`.

A much easier, safer way is to just use `pkill`:

```
pkill -f 'java -Droute=full'
```

This replaces your entire script.

Comment: I tried this but I got this error: pkill: invalid option -- 'D'
And the weird part is when I tried to run the command from Jenkins job, then it is showing error but when I directly run the command in the remote server CLI, it is working fine.

Comment: @tanmay2507: Sounds like a problem with quoting in Jenkins.  Try using double-quotes instead of singles (`"` instead of `'`).  Or maybe you need to escape them for some reason (`\"` or `\\"`).